# Get Size of HTTP Response in Java

Tags: java, http, size, content-length, chunked-encoding

I would like to know how much data was sent in response to a certain http-request.
What I currently do is this:

```
   HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) feedurl.openConnection();
```

//check the response for the content-size
   int feedsize = con.getContentLength();

The problem is, that content-legnth is not always set. E.g. when the server uses transfer-encoding=chunked I get back a value of -1.

I do **not** need this to display progress information. I just need to know the size of the data that was sent to me after it has been done.

Background: I need this information because I would like to compare it to the size of a response, that was sent using gzip encoding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd use a [commons-io CountingInputStream](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/CountingInputStream.html), which would do the job for you. A full but trivial example:

```
public long countContent(URL feedurl) {
  CountingInputStream counter = null;
  try {
     HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) feedurl.openConnection();
     counter = new CountingInputStream(con.getInputStream());
     String output = IOUtils.toString(counter);
     return counter.getByteCount();
  } catch (IOException ex) {
     throw new RuntimeException(ex);
  } finally {
     IOUtils.closeQuietly(counter);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I needed. And with maven one more dependencies won't hurt ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can extend `FilterInputStream`, overriding the `read()`, `read(byte[],int,int)`, and `skip` methods so that after calling the `super` form, they update a counter with the number of bytes read.

Then wrap the input stream returned by `URLConnection` with one of these, and use the wrapper in place of the original stream. When you're done, you can query wrapper's its counter.

Other ("manual") approaches would be use a tool like YSlow to gather statistics in a browser, or Wireshark to examine the traffic on the network.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I must admit, that I am not a very good and also a very lazy coder. I don't like to invent my own wheel/hack for this. So to avoid mistakes  and save time I will use the CountingInputStream from commons-io as an established solution.

Thanks again for your time!