# Determine size of HTTP Response?

Tags: java, io, httpresponse

Is there a way to determine the size of the `HTTPServletResponse` content?  I read this [get-size-of-http-response-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674129/get-size-of-http-response-in-java) question but sadly where I work I do not have access to CommonsIO :(

The response content consists of a single complex object so I have considered writing it out to a temp file and then checking that file.  This is not something I want to be doing as a diagnostic while the application is running in production though so want to avoid it if at all possible.

PS I read erickson's answer but it mentioned input streams I want to know the size of the object being written out...  Would be really nice if the `writeObject()` method returned a number representing bytes written instead of `void`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found a way to get what I wanted:

```
URLConnection con = servletURL.openConnection();
BufferedInputStream bif = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(bif);
int avail = bif.available();

System.out.println("Response content size = " + avail);
```

This allowed me to see the response size on the client.  I still would like to know what it is on the server side before it is sent but this was the next best thing.

Comment: Odd that I get down voted to my own response to my own question for an answer that does exactly what I want...

Answer (score 15):

If you have access to the response header, you can read the `Content-Length`.

Here is a example of a response header:

```
(Status-Line):HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection:Keep-Alive
Date:Fri, 25 Mar 2011 16:26:56 GMT
Content-Length:728
```

Check this out: [Header Field Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)

Comment: It appears the content length of the response does not have to be set.  In my client code I tried URLConnection.getContentLength() and I keep getting -1.  So what must I do on the server side to ensure the content length of the response is calculated?  But if I could do that on the server side my problem would be solved :)

Comment: You can include it in the response header in your server just before send the response to the client.

Comment: Note: This is not present if `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.coderanch.com/t/364514/Servlets/java/calculate-size-output-HttpServletResponse) seems to be what you're looking for:

```
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
...
int len = dos.size();
```

Comment: I think this is your best option because I assume you want to know the size of the outputstream being sent not being received.

Comment: But there is no writeObject() method on the DataOutputStream - I would have to make very significant modifications to the application to reduce everything to primitives.

Comment: I get "java.lang.IllegalStateException: getWriter() has already been called for this response"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the use of `ObjectOutputStream`, build it around a `java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream`:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream contentBytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

ObjectOutputStream objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(contentBytes);

objectOut.writeObject(content);

int contentLength = contentBytes.size();
```

And then you can send the content with

```
contentBytes.writeTo(connection.getOutputStream());
```

where `connection` is whatever you're getting your `OutputStream` from.

Better late than never, right?

Answer (score 0):

if you use Catalina, this worked for me:

```
import org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade
...
long len=((ResponseFacade) response).getContentWritten();
```