# How to calculate Page Response Time using URLConnection?

Tags: java, jsoup, urlconnection

so here is my function

```
public String getPageResponseSize() {
    try {            
        URLConnection con = new URL("http://" + url).openConnection();
        BufferedInputStream bf = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
        int avail = bf.available();
        System.out.println(avail);
        return avail + "";
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JSoupParsing.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JSoupParsing.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return "There is a problem currently with this feature";
}
```

i got some reference from this question
//attention [Determine size of HTTP Response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435351/determine-size-of-http-response)

but I am getting a wrong value comparing the value XXXKb Transferred in "Network" tab of Inspect Element

I want to calculate an approximately equal value as to make a report, help!
(If the solution is possible using JSoup library please show me refs)

Comment: Is the Content-Length header set? You could also just read all the bytes and check the length. That would better simulate a normal page response anyway. Your title is also wrong.

Comment: **content length** is not necessarily always present in the header, thats why I am using available() method which calculates the available bytes to read, 
title wrong? didn't get you. 
reading all the bytes? Do you mean using read() method and count++ till read() returns -1?

Comment: The `available()` method returns the amount of bytes that can be read without blocking. This is **not** the same as the total amount of bytes. The title is talking about Page Response Time, but your question is about counting bytes. Yes, I do mean using `read(byte[] b)` and counting the bytes as you read them.

Comment: thannks, for the reply @Kayaman will try that way now